# Display CSS button in Outlook

Tags: html, css, button, outlook, newsletter

I created a CSS gradient button with [Button Maker](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ButtonMaker/) but it doesn't display properly in Outlook given their CSS restrictions. I therefore want to have a more simple looking button displayed in Outlook but I haven't managed to fill the background between my border and the text link (5px padding around text needs to be filled). I specified background-color:#65a9d7 both in the span style and in the link style.

My problem:[my button in outlook](http://attitudeasbl.webs.com/btn.png)

My button code:

```
<span class="buttoncustom" style="background-color:#65a9d7"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" title="Button" style="text-decoration:none;color:#FFFFFF; padding:5px;background-color:#65a9d7"><strong>&#62; My Button</strong></a></span>
```

My stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .buttoncustom {
           border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
           background: #65a9d7;
           background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
           background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
           background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
           background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
           background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
           padding: 5px 10px;
           -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
           -moz-border-radius: 8px;
           border-radius: 8px;
           -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
           -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
           box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
           text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
           color: white;
           font-size: 14px;
           font-family: Georgia, serif;
           text-decoration: none;
           vertical-align: middle;
           mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
           }
        .buttoncustom:hover {
           border-top-color: #006699;
           background: #006699;
           color: #ccc;
           }
        .buttoncustom:active {
           border-top-color: #1b435e;
           background: #1b435e;
           }
    </style>
```

I've been playing around with the code for ages to no avail so I'd appreciate your help enormously!

Answer (score 6):

I find that using a border of the same colour as the button background is a reliable workaround. So instead of this:

```
a.button { background: #dddddd; padding: 8px; }
```

Try this:

```
a.button { background: #dddddd; border: 8px solid #dddddd; }
```

Answer (score 5):

See Campaign Monitor's tool for making bulletproof buttons in email. Uses VML for Outlook with a fallback display for when images are turned off:

[buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/)

Answer (score 5):

As other answers suggest, the support for anything really universal in Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013 is pretty terrible. The main problem in the case of this button is that the margin property is not supported in these versions of Outlook (they use MS Word as the rendering engine, yuk!) [Litmus explains this and the solution very well](https://litmus.com/help/email-clients/outlookcom-margins/).

I managed to create an [HTML table-based button](http://codepen.io/gillytech/pen/hdoLm) that will work in almost all major email clients.

Here is the HTML for your reference:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellmargin="0" border="0" height="44" width="178" style="border-collapse: collapse; border:5px solid #c62228">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#c62228" valign="middle" align="center" width="174">
      <div style="font-size: 18px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 0; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0;">
        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; border: 0; font-family: Arial, arial, sans-serif; mso-table-lspace:0; mso-table-rspace:0;" border="0">MY BUTTON</a>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this is still helpful to you or any googler that happens by.

Comment: It looks good, but the problem with this one is that the button itself is not clickable. Just the text.

Comment: This is working. Thank you. Anyway to make it have a border radius?

Comment: @Si8 You're welcome. Unfortunately the only way to achieve this effect in Outlook is to add rounded images on each corner in a table matrix. I find it easier to make the button an image OR just let the corners be square the way Microsoft God intended.

Answer (score 2):

Litmus has a great blog post on various options and support for this. I typically use Padding + Border option. I find that it works in all the major clients (except lotus notes).

https://litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design

Note: when testing you need a proper url in the link, if you just have a hash in there it wont work in outlook.com because they strip the link out!

Answer (score 2):

Please use below mentioned HTML code this works perfectly well in outlook.

```
<table cellpadding="0" align="left" cellspacing="0" style="border-radius:2px; background-color:#5794FF; color:#FFFFFF">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" height="32" style="padding:0px 19px; height:32px; font-size:14px; line-height:12px">
                <a href="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF">Search Google</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to style the anchor directly?

```
.buttoncustom a {
       border: 1px solid #96d1f8;
       background: #65a9d7;
       padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Comment: padding is basically ignored. this doesn't work. it will make a white space between the border and the text with background.